# How to send a message from inside a function (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I'm working on a bot for a game me and my friends made and wanted to include a secret command. When it is triggered, it will count down (while sending some messages at certain intervals) then do a certain action.
In order to get the timing correct, I've used the `setTimeout` feature, but now I'm running into a problem: For some reason, I can't send a message from inside a function. Is there a way to get around this restriction? Alternatively, is there another way to complete the command after a certain delay?

```js
if(command === 'purge') {
    console.log('Starting first message/countdown')
    message.channel.send('WARNING: PURGE PRECEPT INITATED. THIS SERVER WILL BE DELETED IN: 60 SECONDS.')
    setTimeout(purge1, 15000);
}

function purge2() {
    console.log('Starting third message/countdown')
    message.channel.send('WARNING: PURGE PRECEPT INITIATED. THIS SERVER WILL BE DELETED IN: 30 SECONDS.');
    setTimeout(purge3, 15000)
}
```

Not quite sure how to format code, sorry. Yes I do have the other stuff (Readying client, login, etc.) but that is the main part relevant to the question.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Done @Lioness100. Sorry for terrible formatting.

Comment: Are you able to send a message inside the if-statement? And not inside the purge2() function? I'm not seeing you call purge2(), or is that done elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is `message` is not defined within the function so what you should do is:
Add a `message` parameter in the function and then pass it when you call the function, for example:

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
    SendHello(message);
}
function SendHello(message){
    message.channel.send('Hello');
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do I leave the message parameter or do I replace what I want the message sent to be? What if I have multiple messages I want to send (inside dms)?